# Why does the below code give erros? This is java FX. The error says "double cannot be dereferenced"

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

```
    RadialGradient gradient1 = new RadialGradient(            
    0,    // focusAngle            
    .1,   // focusDistance            
    80,   // centerX            
    45,   // centerY            
    120,  // radius            
    false, // proportional            
    CycleMethod.REFLECT, // cycleMethod            
    new Stop(0, Color.YELLOW),               
    new Stop(1, Color.BLUE)    
    );


    Slider slider = new Slider(0, 100, 50);
    slider.setLayoutX(30);        
    slider.setLayoutY(90); 
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
    slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider.setMajorTickUnit(100);
    slider.setMinorTickCount(20);
    slider.setBlockIncrement(5);

    **gradient1.getRadius().bind(slider.valueProperty());**

    root.getChildren().add(slider);
```

The line of code between asterisks gives errors. This code is part of a JavaFX application, and I have no idea why I can't bind radius to the slider value

Answer (score 0):

`RadialGradient` is immutable. Even if it wasn't you'd need to use the property for the binding, not the value getter method, i.e. `gradient1.radiusProperty().bind(...`.

You need to bind the whole `RadialGradient` object to the properties where it's used:

```
final Stop stop1 = new Stop(0, Color.YELLOW);
final Stop stop2 = new Stop(1, Color.BLUE);

ObjectBinding<RadialGradient> gradientBinding = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> new RadialGradient(            
    0,    // focusAngle            
    .1,   // focusDistance            
    80,   // centerX            
    45,   // centerY            
    slider.getValue(),  // radius            
    false, // proportional            
    CycleMethod.REFLECT, // cycleMethod            
    stop1,               
    stop2    
    ), slider.valueProperty());
```

```
Rectangle rect = ...
rect.fillProperty().bind(gradientBinding);
```

Answer (score 0):

gradient1.getRadius() has return type double.

double cannot be deferenced in this case as it's a primitive type.

You're most likely looking for a DoubleProperty or something in that gradient. You need to find a workaround with a changelistener.

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener((x)->{/* modify gradient value here */})
```

Additionally, direct cross-property bindings have been subject to memory leaks in the past. At one point i've resorted to modifying everything that invoked .bind(**) in some of my projects into something i've described beforehand. You should check whether the workaround is still needed.